# Динамическая корзина на чистом JS, необходима помощь в доработке

Tags: javascript, dom

1. количество уходит в минус, не могу поставить ограничение, чтобы количество нельзя было установить отрицательным.
2. кнопка удаления должна полностью очищать корзину покупок
3. внизу должна отображаться полная стоимость корзины, если ничего не выбрано, то должен быть отображен текст "Корзина пустая".

```js
// document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
let main = document.querySelector('.main');
let hd = document.createElement('h1');
hd.className = 'header';
hd.innerHTML = 'This is your basket';
hd.style.textAlign = 'center';
main.appendChild(hd);
let basketWrap = document.createElement('div');
basketWrap.className = 'basket__wrap';
main.appendChild(basketWrap);
let newProd;

// class Basket {
//     constructor(prod, quan, price, url) {
//         this.prod = prod;
//         this.quan = quan;
//         this.price = price;
//         this.url = url;
//     }
//     getPriceProd() {
//         return this.price * this.quan;
//     }
// }

function createProdItem(prod, price, quan) {
  newProd = document.createElement('div');
  newProd.className = 'prod__wrap';
  newProd.innerHTML = `
 <div class="prod__header">${prod}</div>
 <div class="prod__price">${price}</div>
 <div class="count">
 <button class="minus">-</button>
 <div class="number">0</div>
 <button class="plus">+</button>
</div>
 <button class="delete">DELETE</button>`;
  basketWrap.appendChild(newProd);
}
createProdItem("pizza", 1500, 0);
createProdItem("sandwich", 120, 0);
createProdItem("ice", 100, 0);

function sumProd(price, quan) {
  return this.price * this.quan;
}
// let basket = document.createElement('div');
// basket.className = 'basket';
// main.appendChild(basket);
// let sum = document.createElement('div');
// sum.className = 'sumBasket';
// sum.appendChild


// -----------------------------------------------
// let buy = document.querySelectorAll('.buy');
let del = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');

let info = document.querySelector('.basket__info');
let sum = document.querySelector('.sum__price');
// let counts = document.querySelectorAll('.count');
function addHandlers(count) {
  var minus = count.querySelector(".minus");
  var number = count.querySelector(".number");
  var plus = count.querySelector(".plus");
  plus.addEventListener("click", function() {
    number.innerText++;
  });
  minus.addEventListener("click", function() {
    number.innerText--;
  });
}
var counts = document.querySelectorAll(".count");
counts.forEach(addHandlers);

function sumPrice() {
  return this.number * this.price;
}
// plus.addEventListener('click', plusBtn);
let basketInfo = document.createElement('div');
basketInfo.className = 'basket__info';
basketInfo.innerHTML =
  `<div class="basket__info">Корзина пуста</div>
<div class="sum__price">0</div>`;
main.appendChild(basketInfo);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.delete {
  background: red;
}

.delete:hover {
  background: darkred;
}

.buy {
  background: chartreuse;
}

.buy:hover {
  background: green;
}

.prod__header {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.prod__price {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.minus,
.quan,
.plus {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

не самое лучшее решение, но работает 1 пункт) Логика неправильная, нужно переделывать. Даю ссылку, делал что-то подобное, думаю разберешься без проблем
[пример](https://github.com/zhyvkoroma/shop)

```js
// document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let main = document.querySelector('.main');
    let hd = document.createElement('h1');
    hd.className = 'header';
    hd.innerHTML = 'This is your basket';
    hd.style.textAlign = 'center';
    main.appendChild(hd);
    let basketWrap = document.createElement('div');
    basketWrap.className = 'basket__wrap';
    main.appendChild(basketWrap);
    let newProd;
    
    // class Basket {
    //     constructor(prod, quan, price, url) {
    //         this.prod = prod;
    //         this.quan = quan;
    //         this.price = price;
    //         this.url = url;
    //     }
    //     getPriceProd() {
    //         return this.price * this.quan;
    //     }
    // }
    
    function createProdItem(prod, price, quan) {
        newProd = document.createElement('div');
        newProd.className = 'prod__wrap';
        newProd.innerHTML = `
     <div class="prod__header">${prod}</div>
     <div class="prod__price">${price}</div>
     <div class="count">
     <button class="minus">-</button>
     <div class="number">0</div>
     <button class="plus">+</button>
    </div>
     <button class="delete">DELETE</button>`;
        basketWrap.appendChild(newProd);
    }
    createProdItem("pizza", 1500, 0);
    createProdItem("sandwich", 120, 0);
    createProdItem("ice", 100, 0);
    function sumProd(price, quan) {
        return this.price * this.quan;
    }
    // let basket = document.createElement('div');
    // basket.className = 'basket';
    // main.appendChild(basket);
    // let sum = document.createElement('div');
    // sum.className = 'sumBasket';
    // sum.appendChild
    
    
    // -----------------------------------------------
    // let buy = document.querySelectorAll('.buy');
    let del = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');
    
    let info = document.querySelector('.basket__info');
    let sum = document.querySelector('.sum__price');
    // let counts = document.querySelectorAll('.count');
    function addHandlers(count) {
        var minus = count.querySelector(".minus");
        var number = count.querySelector(".number");
        var plus = count.querySelector(".plus");
        plus.addEventListener("click", function() {
          number.innerText++;
        });
        console.log(number.textContent);
        minus.addEventListener("click", function() {
          if(number.textContent == 0){
              number.textContent = 0
          } else {
            number.innerText--;
          }
        });
      }
      var counts = document.querySelectorAll(".count");
      counts.forEach(addHandlers);
      function sumPrice () {
          return this.number * this.price;
      }
    // plus.addEventListener('click', plusBtn);
    let basketInfo = document.createElement('div');
    basketInfo.className = 'basket__info';
    basketInfo.innerHTML =
        `<div class="basket__info">Корзина пуста</div>
    <div class="sum__price">0</div>`;
    main.appendChild(basketInfo);
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
img {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.delete {
    background: red;
}
.delete:hover {
    background: darkred;
}
.buy {
    background: chartreuse;
}
.buy:hover {
    background: green;
}
.prod__header {
    font-size: 30px;
}
.prod__price {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.minus, .quan, .plus {
    display: inline;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>Basket</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main"></div>

    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```